# Inequality with fraction and rad

Tags: inequality

$$2\cdot\sqrt{-5x-1}>5x$$

Tried 5 times but I’m doing something wrong.
There’s a step where i should divide in all the possible cases but I don’t understand why and how...

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: would be great if you can  share the $5$th attempt in the post so that we can fix the error =)

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh yup i’m writing it, but it takes some time with mathjax... My error is that step of dividing possibilities :)

Comment: Please fix your math expression. To write the square root of `...`  you type this `\sqrt{ ... }`

Comment: Multiplication is indicated by either `\cdot` symbol or just a blank space when appropriate

Comment: try to surround 2\cdot \sqrt{-5x-1} > 5x with dollar sign. Looking ahead, if you want to write fraction \frac{3}{5} produces $\frac35$. Use ^ for superscript. curly braces is useful to define an environment.

Comment: Thanks for the edit

Comment: Hints: First, determine when the root is defined. Second: square both sides ...

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh you don't need the curly braces if the fractions are one-digit, \frac35 also makes $\frac35$.

Comment: I agree, but in case more digits are needed. =)

Comment: @MattiP. In this case no need to square. In fact, that even could make things much messier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *it must* be $\;-5x-1\ge0\iff x\le-\frac15\;$ , the right side is negative, and since the left side is always non-negative, the inequality is true always **within** its definition domain, i.e.: for any $\;x\le-\frac15\;$

Comment: Thanks a lot, i found your solution easier and more about reasoning. Guess it’s not always possible but thanks a lot :) a different point of view!

Comment: I agree, this full & short solution is much easier than mine!